# find occurrence of string and stored it in array

Tags: c#, regex

I have a svg file in string format which look like this http://jsfiddle.net/mumg81qq/5/ This file contains color code in either hex/rgb format.

i want to extract these two different types of colors format in two arrays.

hex colors could be in format of

```
fill:#303744 
---OR---
fill="#020202"
```

and rgb colors could be in format of

```
fill:rgb(48,49,55)
---OR---
fill="rgb(205,149,36)"
```

resultant array should look like this

`hexColor = ["#303744","#020202"]`

`rgbColor = ["rgb(48,49,55)","rgb(205,149,36)"]`

I could only managed to write code which search *one type of hex string* .

```
string searchHex1 = "fill=\"#", searchHex2 = "fill:#";
string searchRGB1 = "fill=\"rgb(", searchRGB2 = "fill:rgb(";

List<string> hexColor = new List<string>();
List<string> rgbColor = new List<string>();

string sHexColor = "";
int index = 0;
do
{
    index = svgFile.IndexOf(searchHex1, index);
    if (index != -1)
    {
        sHexColor = svgFile.Substring(index, 7);
        if (!hexColor.Contains(sHexColor))
        {
            hexColor.Add(sHexColor);
        }
        index++;
    }
} while (index != -1);
```

**in most efficient way i want to search 4 different types of hex & rgb colors and store it in two different arrays.**

Comment: you want to use regex for this. You can get a matchcollection and then iterate it to add it to your array.

Comment: @AntoineLev could you provide code sample for the same ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like this should work for you where `input` is your file as a string

```
        string hexapattern = @"#[0-9a-fA-F]{6}";
        string rgbpattern = @"rgb\([0-9]+\,[0-9]+\,[0-9]+\)";

        Regex rgxHexa = new Regex(hexapattern);
        MatchCollection matches = rgxHexa.Matches(input);
        foreach (Match match in matches)
        { 
            // add to hexa array
        }


        Regex rgxRGB = new Regex(hexapattern);
        matches = rgxRGB.Matches(input);
        foreach (Match match in matches)
        {
            // add to rgb array
        }
```

and don't forget `using System.Text.RegularExpressions;`

Comment: Will the above `rgbpattern` work if if i have spaces in `rgb(153 , 54 , 98 )` ?

Comment: this one will match both with and without withespaces "rgb\([0-9]+\,\s?[0-9]+\,\s?[[0-9]+\)"

Answer (score 1):

Would be something like this...

```
string hexRegex = @"fill[:=]""?(#[a-fA-F0-9]{6})""?";
string rgbRegex = @"fill[:=]""?(rgb\( *\d{1,3} *, *?\d{1,3} *, *\d{1,3} *\))""?";
string oneRegex = string.Format("({0}|{1})", hexRegex, rgbRegex);

string testdata = @"fill:#303744" + 
                  @"fill=""#020202""" +
                  @"fill:rgb(48,49,55)" +
                  @"fill=""rgb(205,149,36)""";

IEnumerable<string> colorCodes = Regex.Matches(testdata, oneRegex)
                                      .Cast<Match>()
                                      .Select(match => match.Groups[1].Value.Replace(" ",""));
```

[image: Result]

Answer (score 0):

Here's the one-liner version:

```
var hexMatches = Regex.Matches(svg, @"(?<=fill:|="")#[0-9a-fA-F]{6}")
    .Cast<Match>().Select (m => m.Value).ToList();
var rgbMatches = Regex.Matches(svg, @"(?<=fill:|="")rgb\((\d{1,3},?){3}\)")
    .Cast<Match>().Select (m => m.Value).ToList();
```

You'll notice the use of positive lookbehind's:

```
(?<=fill:|="")
```

They are entirely optional and are only there so that you don't get unwanted matches in case some other color values get introduced that *aren't* a fill. I don't know much about the origins of the file, so I'll leave it up to you to keep them or not.